# Queries about string and date sizes

Tags: c

I would like to ask what is the applicable/suitable or standard sizes for string and date? Is 256 for string size and 20 for date size alright?

Comment: Length *constraints* and buffer sizes are two different concerns. For an input buffer any size will do, but if it's large enough to handle any of your input forms that's ideal. In your structures try and use `char*` to handle *any* length, avoid using `char x[N]` where `N` might be an assumption that's wrong. It's easier to relax your validations than it is to change tons of code that has lengths baked in.

Comment: For dates, it depends on what formats you expect.  If you plan to allow "Wednesday, 27th September, 2017", then you need a size of 32 for the date string.  If you don't plan to be so generous, you can get away with a shorter string.  For general string input, there's no one right size.  It depends on what you're going to store.  Tweets are up to 280 characters — and I expect they're Unicode (UTF-8) characters using 1-4 bytes each.  For that, 256 bytes isn't big enough.  For many other uses, it is probably sufficient.  But it all depends on your application.

Comment: For date/time, research [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for standard time string encodings.  (suggest 64)

Comment: FWIW, the longest timezone I found was "America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia" (32)

Answer (score 0):

You're literary asking how long a string is

There is no way of defining a good standard size. It all comes down to the requirements in the specific case.

Regarding dates, what date format will you use? Make sure the array can handle the largest instance of that format. If you want to use "YYMMDD", then a size of 7 is enough.

For the general case it all boils down to what the string should contain. A much more important aspect than how long it should be is how you handle cases when a certain size is not enough. Do you truncate the string?

If the strings are expected to vary a lot in size, or if they are really big, or moderately big but many, consider using dynamic allocation with `malloc` instead of a fixed size to not overflow the stack.